# Проблема с выводом в списке

Tags: python, циклы, list, список

Не могу понять в чем проблема
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
n=[i for i in input().split()]
need,howmany,lst=input(),0,[]
for i in n:
    if i==need:
        lst.append(n.index(i)+howmany)
        howmany+=1
        n.remove(i)
print(*lst)
```

Comment: Хотя я уже зделал другим способом,но мне интересно в чем проблема

Comment: А проблема-то в чем? Особенно, если "уже сделали"?

Comment: @ryan123rudder, что Вас не устраивает в коде? Ошибка какая-то вылезает или код не так работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вашего кода в следующем: когда вы удаляете элемент и переходите к следующему, получается так что вы пропускаете следующий. Вот был у вас массив **[1, 2, 2, 3]**, в котором вы удаляете **2**. Вы идете по массиву, встречаете первую двойку, удаляете ее (у нее индекс 1), потом итератор сдвигается и теперь вы смотрите на элемент с индексом 2, то есть тройку в нашем случае (массив [1, 2, 3]). И в результате ваша программа вместо правильного ответа: **1, 2**; выводит только **1**.